# Does vector.reserve() optimize for vector.insert()

Tags: c++, vector

I understand that vector.reserve() adds new spaces to the end for new additions to a vector, but will the vector re-copy if I insert a value in? If i reserve a size 1 bigger than the current size and insert a value in, will it recopy the entire vector or optimize it so it doesn't do that?

Comment: what would be the use of `reserve` if the reserved memory isn't used for subsequent insertions?

Comment: Depends on where you do the insert. If you insert at the beginning of the vector then the entire vector is getting copied no matter what,

Comment: Yes, my bad I should have been more specific. Ok, with that, if i insert it at the 10th index and its 20 long, and reserve gives it capacity of 21, will it only re-copy the 11th-20th index's?

Comment: @peterwilson It'll leave the elements before the insertion point untouched and move (or copy) the elements from the supplied iterator position and up.

Comment: @peterwilson Yes, reserve prevents copying due to *reallocation*, but not the copying of elements that is inherent in the operation concerned.

Comment: Alright, cheers guys that helps a bunch!

Comment: Oh, wait, just looking into reserve, If my vector is 20 in size, and i type myVec.reserve(1) that doesn't add another slot does it? If i call myVec.reserve(21) that would be what I need?

Comment: @peterwilson Yes, `myVec.reserve(1)` would do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`reserve(X)` makes sure that the `capacity()` is *at least* X. It can be higher due to rounding or prior bigger reservations.

If the capacity is sufficient, methods that adds one or more elements to the vector will not cause a reallocation.

If the capacity grows, either because of a `reserve` or automatically when adding new elements, existing elements will need to be copied (or moved).

Answer (score 1):

Reserve force a [reallocation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) if the `reserve` value is greater than the capacity, if that happen the moving/copying happens when called and not on insert. Also all iterators will be invalidated.

Calling reserve with a value one higher than capacity is counter productive as the insert will do it for you.

Comment: "... as the insert will do it for you." More like "*... as it will override the exponential growth strategy necessary for amortized constant cost of appending.*" [See cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

Comment: @Deduplicator that is also true.